# How to create a circular Alphabet in Python so that the letter after z is a and the letter before a is z

Tags: python, ascii, circular-list, alphabet

Is there a Function in Python to easily create a circular Alphabet, so that the letter after z is a and the letter before a is z?

I tried something with `chr()` and `.join(Alphabet)`, but that didn't worked because i got the error message `an integer is required (got type str)`.

```py
for character in word:
    if chr(Alphabet[Alphabet.find(character)) >= "z":
        new_Alphabet = Alphabet.join(Alphabet)
    elif chr(Alphabet[Alphabet.find(character)) <= "a":
        new_Alphabet = Alphabet.join(Alphabet[:-1])
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) ans [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase):

```
from itertools import cycle
import string
circular_alphabet = cycle(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

That is an infinite iterator with the lowercase letters:

```
>>> "".join(next(circular_alphabet ) for _ in range(50))
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `circular queue`. for more information please check this [link](https://www.pythoncentral.io/circular-queue/).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative (old fashion?) solution:

```
def cycle_letter(ch,up=True):
  upper = 'A' <= ch <= 'Z'
  ch = ch.lower()
  letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  pos = letters.find(ch)
  if pos < 0: return ch
  length = len(letters)
  pos += 1 if up else length-1
  ans = letters[pos%length]
  if upper: ans = ans.upper()
  return ans

################################################################################

def cycle_string(s,up=True):
  return ''.join(cycle_letter(ch,up) for ch in s)

################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':    #Test
  s = cycle_string('Hello, World!')
  print(s)
  s = cycle_string(s,False)
  print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, this snippet shifts a word by the desired number of spaces. (e.g. `shift_word('abcdef', 12) = 'opqrst'` )

```py
def shift_word(word: str, spaces: int) -> str:
    first_ordinal = 97
    last_ordinal = 122
    alphabet_size = 26

    return ''.join(chr((ord(letter) - last_ordinal - spaces - 1) % alphabet_size + first_ordinal) for letter in word)
```

It simply iterates over the word letter-by-letter, applies some modulo math to calculate the right "bucket" where the letter should fall, and makes sure the result is in the boundaries of ordinals 97-122 (letters a-z)